# How to get progress informations when upload files to Digital Ocean Spaces with Flutter

Tags: flutter, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

I'm trying to use Digital Ocean Spaces as file storage for my Flutter application. As API helper I'm using the package `minio` (https://pub.dev/packages/minio).

In general I can start upload and download operations. But I can't find a way to get progress informations.

I tried to set a bucket event like this:

```
void bucketListener() {
    // Listener
    final poller = minio.listenBucketNotification(bucket, events: [
      's3:PutObject:*',
    ]);
    poller.stream.listen((event) {
      print(event);
      print('--- event: ${event['eventName']}');
      // Get.find<EntriesController>(tag: "newEntry").videoUploadProgress[0];
    });
  }
```

But this listener not fires. Then here I found that Digital Ocean does not support Bucket Informations: https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/spaces/

Is there a way to get the upload progress when using the Digital Ocean storage? Thanks for your help!